# can I get any money back from US after deportation?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, social-security, citizenship

I was living in US for 16 years and had a green card and Social Security number. Most of my years there I was working and paying taxes. Got deported after serving 3 year sentence for drug offence.

Can I claim any money for retirement from US? I am getting close to retirement age and now live in UK.

Comment: What specific money are you talking about? Money that belonged to you in a US bank account? Money owed you by a previous employer? Pension? etc.

Comment: The US has a [totalization agreement](https://www.ssa.gov/international/agreements_overview.html) with the UK, which I believe would normally allow counting of US Social Security credits towards qualification for UK retirement benefits. I am not sure whether the deportation affects this.

Answer (score 4):

The only one I can think of is Social Security, and it looks like deportation specifically disallows SS benefits:

"Section 202(n)(1) or section 223 of the Act prohibits the number holder (NH) on a Social Security record from receiving his or her title II retirement and/or disability benefits when SSA receives notice from DHS that the NH has been deported or removed from the United States under any of the sections of the INA that are listed in the definitions in RS 02635.001C." https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/poms.nsf/lnx/0302635001

It looks like if you could somehow swing permanent residence again, you might be able to get benefits reinstated, but it's probably a bit too much work to do that just to get access to benefits. Also, if you have dependents, they might be able to get SS, even if you can't.